# How do I fix corrupted partitions within a hyper-v machine?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I can see the folders with listing them (dir) but if I try listing files I get corrupted files errors.

System is still booting up to either normal startup (With blue screen) or system repair startup (which gives me a command prompt where I get the error)

It's a virtual machine so no hardware changes have been made.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Windows Server 2012 host or server around, you could try mounting the virtual disk and then run chkdsk to repair it

Try the free Microsoft vhdtool (http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vhdtool) that includes  a"repair" function which is designed to undo an expand operation on a base VHD when differencing VHDs are present

There is a guide here which could be useful: http://arnulfowing.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/how-to-get-hyper-v-to-read-corrupted.html